# Core Animation with Blocks on the Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-animation, objective-c-blocks

Is it possible to perform animations with Core Animation using blocks on the Mac similarly to how one can do it on iOS? I'd like to be able to set up completion blocks at the end of an animation to remove views, etc. I know that this can be achieved with delegates, but obviously  the whole point of blocks with animations is to avoid that pain.

Answer (score 3):

CATransaction + (void)setCompletionBlock:(void (^)(void))block

The block object called when animations for this transaction group are completed.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:5.0];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{ 
    // this will be done when animation has completed
}];
//do some things to your layers
[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 1):

Twitter is offering TwUI that uses Core Animation with Blocks. It might help you.

https://github.com/twitter/twui

https://github.com/twitter/twui/blob/master/lib/UIKit/TUIView+Animation.m

```
@interface TUIViewAnimation : NSObject <CAAction>
{
    /* snip */
    void (^animationCompletionBlock)(BOOL finished);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes.** NSAnimationContext and NSAnimationGroup both have `completionHandler` properties to which you can assign blocks, but many others don't.